# How can I reassign the copy/paste keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I've been using mac for years, but prefer to do software development on windows. I'm really used to is using the folowing shortcuts on windows very much:

```
<CTRL>  + INSERT: Copy
<SHIFT> + INSERT: Paste
<SHIFT> + DELETE: Cut
```

Of late, I've taken to doing even my development work on the Mac. However, as a matter of habit, I'm missing these shortcuts very much. Actually, I find these a lot more convenient than COMMAND + (C/V/X) combo.

Is there a way to reassign these three shortcuts at least?

I've look all over the internet and in the "Keyboards" system preferences but I did not find anything.

PS: If you're wondering where I find the INSERT keys on a mac book pro, I use a wireless keyboard.

Comment: Related: [Remap Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, and Ctrl-X only](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/66970/22781)

Comment: https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
System Preferences: Keyboard: Modifier Keys...
```

Then swap the Command and Control keys. This will change everything globally for all keyboard commands system-wide.

[image]

Comment: Any way to make command+left or command+right go one word left or one word right instead of home and end?

Comment: I really wish there was a poll somewhere of mac users who actually make this switch.

Comment: This also messes up our dear ALT-TAB !

Comment: How is this answering <SHIFT> + INSERT: Paste ?

Comment: But that would change ALL keyboard shortcuts where the CONTROL key is used!

Answer (score 80):

This worked great for me to serve just the cut/paste/copy features I use so often[image]

Comment: This doesn't work very well in some apps such as Finder. The problem is that sometimes the Menu item is named "Copy 6 items" or Copy file.txt, and then it doesn't work

Comment: How do you figure out the names for shortcuts? where can i see all available ones? because in my os there is only show help menu and nothing more... no autocomplete on new shortcut dialog

Comment: for copy paste its logical but for example CTRL + Back i dont know the name and want to change it to Command + Back

Comment: This worked for me. Added bunch of commands from VSCode to mach windows shortcuts.

Comment: Important to note that changes may not take effect until restarting an application.

Comment: In addition to them, add CTRL+A for Select All

Comment: Alone like this is does not work for me

Comment: @HalilİbrahimOymacı I recommend against ctrl-A. If you're a heavy bash/zsh terminal user ctrl-A will remove the very useful "go to beginning of the line." It is standard on linux desktop systems to use `shift` + `ctrl` + `<key>`, which seems to solve this for me on MacOS.

Comment: It seems to be a great solution, but I cannot setup the Undo option with `CTRL-z`, it doesn't work

Comment: @DavidLeal I did it just now and called Undo "Revert"

Comment: I was switching the Control and Command keys, but this created issues inside of IntelliJ as it forces an emulated terminal which can not compensate for the command key in the .zshrc file. Using this method to over-ride the applications isn't perfect, but it seems to work in many cases so far.

Comment: To reach the screenshot shown in the answer: System Preferences: Keyboard: Shortcuts

Comment: Doesnt work for Select All in chrome

Answer (score 14):

Try creating `~/Library/KeyBindings/` and saving a property list like this as [DefaultKeyBinding.dict](http://lri.me/keybindings.htm):

```
{
    "^\UF727" = copy:; // control-insert
    "$\UF727" = paste:; // shift-insert
    "^\UF728" = cut:; // control-delete
}
```

I don't have a keyboard with an insert key, so I couldn't test if the first two settings work. The last setting works for me though.

Edit: another option is to use [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) (formerly KeyRemap4MacBook):

[image]

```
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::PC_INSERT, VK_CONTROL | Modifierflag::NONE KeyCode::C, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::PC_INSERT, VK_SHIFT | Modifierflag::NONE, KeyCode::V, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::FORWARD_DELETE, VK_SHIFT | Modifierflag::NONE, KeyCode::X, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
```

Comment: Gave it a shot. It doesn't seem to work. Guess I'll have to get used to mac clipboard shortcuts. Thanks much. I'll try and read up on the links. First look, I didn't  understand most of the things in these links :)

Comment: Created an account just to mod this up. KeyRemap4MacBook finally made me able to use ctrl/shift+ins/del on mac, this has really made my coding so much faster. I've dabbled with DoubleCommand, custom keymaps etc but this one just worked right out of the box.

Comment: @Arne Sadly the application stopped working with Sierra update.  The KeyBindings file approach has never worked for me.

Comment: On a standard PC keyboard the code for the `Ins` key is `F746` (not `F727`). `Del` is still `F728` as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 9):

I use Ctrl-Ins, Shift-Ins, etc too.

The solution described is [here](http://heisencoder.net/2008/04/fixing-up-mac-key-bindings-for-windows.html), as well as remapping Home and End keys to be more Windows-like, e.g.

> - Open TextEdit under the Applications folder.  If TextEdit was already open, create a new document using `File->New`.  There should be
>   a window labeled `Untitled`.
> - Select the text within the window below, copy it, and then paste it into your new TextEdit window.
> - In TextEdit, convert this to plain text (the default is rich text) by selecting `Format->Make Plain Text`.
> - Next, select `File->Save...`  In the `Save As` dialog box, navigate to your home directory (look under PLACES on the left side for a house
>   picture that has your name next to it). In your home directory,
>   double-click on the `Library` folder.
>
>   - If you don't see the `Library` folder, then press `Cmd+Shift+G` (or `Ctrl+Shift+G`) and in the `Go to the folder:` dialog type `~/Library` and press `Go` button.
> - If you see a `KeyBindings` folder then double-click on it.  If not, then double-click on `Library` folder first to select it, then on the `New Folder` button, name the new folder `KeyBindings` (with no
>   space), and then double-click on it.  Type `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` for
>   the filename (at the top, in the `Save As:` field).
> - Uncheck `If no extension is provided, use ".txt"` checkbox at the bottom of the `Save As:` dialog, read the warning below and then click `Save`.
> - **Warning**:  TextEdit will sometimes try to "help" you by appending a `.txt` extension to the filename.  Make sure this doesn't happen.  If
>   asked to use a `.txt` extension, tell TextEdit to instead use `.dict`.  It
>   will not work if you use `.txt`.  If you have trouble, see comment by
>   Nathan below.
> - Before these changes take effect, you need to log out and then log back in.

The code to paste into `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` file is this one:

```
/* ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.Dict
This file remaps the key bindings of a single user on Mac OS X 10.5 to more closely
match default behavior on Windows systems.  This particular mapping assumes
that you have also switched the Control and Command keys already.

This key mapping is more appropriate after switching Ctrl for Command in this menu:
Apple->System Preferences->Keyboard & Mouse->Keyboard->Modifier Keys...->
Change Control Key to Command
Change Command key to Control
This applies to OS X 10.5 and possibly other versions.

Here is a rough cheatsheet for syntax.
Key Modifiers
^ : Ctrl
$ : Shift
~ : Option (Alt)
@ : Command (Apple)
# : Numeric Keypad

Non-Printable Key Codes

Up Arrow:     \UF700        Backspace:    \U0008        F1:           \UF704
Down Arrow:   \UF701        Tab:          \U0009        F2:           \UF705
Left Arrow:   \UF702        Escape:       \U001B        F3:           \UF706
Right Arrow:  \UF703        Enter:        \U000A        ...
Insert:       \UF727        Page Up:      \UF72C
Delete:       \UF728        Page Down:    \UF72D
Home:         \UF729        Print Screen: \UF72E
End:          \UF72B        Scroll Lock:  \UF72F
Break:        \UF732        Pause:        \UF730
SysReq:       \UF731        Menu:         \UF735
Help:         \UF746

NOTE: typically the Windows 'Insert' key is mapped to what Macs call 'Help'.  
Regular Mac keyboards don't even have the Insert key, but provide 'Fn' instead, 
which is completely different.
*/

{
"\UF729"   = "moveToBeginningOfLine:";                       /* Home         */
"@\UF729"  = "moveToBeginningOfDocument:";                   /* Cmd  + Home  */
"$\UF729"  = "moveToBeginningOfLineAndModifySelection:";     /* Shift + Home */
"@$\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfDocumentAndModifySelection:"; /* Shift + Cmd  + Home */
"\UF72B"   = "moveToEndOfLine:";                             /* End          */
"@\UF72B"  = "moveToEndOfDocument:";                         /* Cmd  + End   */
"$\UF72B"  = "moveToEndOfLineAndModifySelection:";           /* Shift + End  */
"@$\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfDocumentAndModifySelection:";       /* Shift + Cmd  + End */
"\UF72C"   = "pageUp:";                                      /* PageUp       */
"\UF72D"   = "pageDown:";                                    /* PageDown     */
"$\UF728"  = "cut:";                                         /* Shift + Del  */
"$\UF727"  = "paste:";                                       /* Shift + Ins */
"@\UF727"  = "copy:";                                        /* Cmd  + Ins  */
"$\UF746"  = "paste:";                                       /* Shift + Help */
"@\UF746"  = "copy:";                                        /* Cmd  + Help (Ins) */
"@\UF702"  = "moveWordBackward:";                            /* Cmd  + LeftArrow */
"@\UF703"  = "moveWordForward:";                             /* Cmd  + RightArrow */
"@$\UF702" = "moveWordBackwardAndModifySelection:";   /* Shift + Cmd  + Leftarrow */
"@$\UF703" = "moveWordForwardAndModifySelection:";   /* Shift + Cmd  + Rightarrow */
}
```

Comment: External links can go away. Please relate the most relevant contents here in your answer so the answer will always be here, and the link can serve for deeper research.

Comment: Ha, I forgot I even wrote this answer. I've probably repaved my Mac 5 times since I wrote it, and got used to the Mac shortcuts years ago.

Comment: I think this is the most effective way to replicate Windows/Linux keyboard functionality on a Mac. Confirmed it still works as of 10.15.x.

Comment: Confirmed it still works as of 12.6. However in some application (Firefox) the **Ctrl+Insert** does not copy selected text...

Answer (score 4):

`System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts`

You can change (or assign) several hotkeys by finding in the list and then clicking on the key assigned and then typing the new one to replace.

To replace (for example) a "copy" operation in a specific program add an entry for the program in you are using (or for all programs). In the menu title box, type EXACTLY the menu text of the item i (e.g. Copy) as the text. Restart the application and click on the menu item within the program, you will find that this has been replaced with your custom shortcut

Answer (score 1):

I'm using keyboard maestro since

1. swapping cmd and ctrl is not suitable for working with terminals. You actually need a lot of ctrl.
2. changing it in system preferences doesn't work with some applications.

Copy:
[image]

Undo:
[image]

Paste
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can install and configure [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) app with the following configuration of [`private.xml` file](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en) (edit in *Misc* tab):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Copy with Ctrl-Insert</name>
    <identifier>private.use_ctrl_insert_for_copy</identifier>
    <autogen>
        __KeyToKey__
        KeyCode::PC_INSERT, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L,
        KeyCode::C, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L
    </autogen>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Copy with Ctrl-C</name>
    <identifier>private.use_ctrl_c_for_copy</identifier>
    <autogen>
        __KeyToKey__
        KeyCode::C, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L,
        KeyCode::C, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L
    </autogen>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Cut with Shift-Delete</name>
    <identifier>private.use_shift_delete_for_cut</identifier>
    <autogen>
        __KeyToKey__
        KeyCode::DELETE, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L,
        KeyCode::X, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L
    </autogen>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Cut with Ctrl-X</name>
    <identifier>private.use_ctrl_x_for_cut</identifier>
    <autogen>
        __KeyToKey__
        KeyCode::X, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L,
        KeyCode::X, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L
    </autogen>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Paste with Shift-Insert</name>
    <identifier>private.use_shift_insert_for_paste</identifier>
    <autogen>
        __KeyToKey__
        KeyCode::PC_INSERT, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L,
        KeyCode::V, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L
    </autogen>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Paste with Ctrl-V</name>
    <identifier>private.use_ctrl_v_for_paste</identifier>
    <autogen>
        __KeyToKey__
        KeyCode::V, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L,
        KeyCode::V, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L
    </autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

and enable newly created item after reloading the file in the *Change Key* tab.

Related: [Remap Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, and Ctrl-X only](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/66970/22781)

Answer (score -1):

I can't make Karabiner Elements work for me for Sierra, no Insert key.  I finally decided the issue is that I use my left hand to press modifier keys (ctrl, cmd, opt) and my right hand to press navigation keys (arrows, home, end, insert, delete).  THAT'S WHY Cmd-C and Cmd-V are so awkward.

So I am experimenting with (through the System Keyboard Shortcuts above):

- Cmd-[ for Copy
- Cmd-[ for Paste

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing how this is an actual answer and not commentary/feedback as to your trials/experiments..