# Remap Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, and Ctrl-X only

Tags: macos, keyboard

I know that I can globally swap the `Control` and `Command` in Mac OS and this is not what I need. What I would like to do is keep both buttons as they are and only and make `Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, and Ctrl-X` work as if they were pressed with the `Command` button. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option would be to use [DefaultKeyBinding.dict](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html), but it wouldn't work in all applications or text views.

```
{
    "^x" = cut:;
    "^c" = copy:;
    "^v" = paste:;
}
```

[KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) would work almost everywhere, and it also allows excluding specific applications.

[image]

Here's the [definition of the remapping selected in the screenshot](https://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml):

```
<item>
  <name>Use PC Style Copy/Paste</name>
  <appendix>(Control+C to Command_L+C)</appendix>
  <appendix>(Control+V to Command_L+V)</appendix>
  <appendix>(Control+X to Command_L+X)</appendix>
  <appendix>(Except in Terminal, VM, RDC, Emacs, X11, Eclipse)</appendix>
  <identifier>remap.copy_paste_winstyle_no_term</identifier>
  <not>EMACS, TERMINAL, VIRTUALMACHINE, REMOTEDESKTOPCONNECTION, X11, ECLIPSE</not>
  <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::C, VK_CONTROL, KeyCode::C, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
  <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::V, VK_CONTROL, KeyCode::V, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
  <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::X, VK_CONTROL, KeyCode::X, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install and configue [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) app with the following configuration of [`private.xml` file](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en) (edit in *Misc* tab):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Copy with Ctrl-C</name>
    <identifier>private.use_ctrl_c_for_copy</identifier>
    <autogen>
        __KeyToKey__
        KeyCode::C, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L,
        KeyCode::C, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L
    </autogen>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Cut with Ctrl-X</name>
    <identifier>private.use_ctrl_x_for_cut</identifier>
    <autogen>
        __KeyToKey__
        KeyCode::X, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L,
        KeyCode::X, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L
    </autogen>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Paste with Ctrl-V</name>
    <identifier>private.use_ctrl_v_for_paste</identifier>
    <autogen>
        __KeyToKey__
        KeyCode::V, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L,
        KeyCode::V, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L
    </autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

and enable newly created item after reloading the file in the *Change Key* tab.

Comment: This is more current, since Keymap4MacBook _is_ now Karabiner-Elements.

Comment: Where do you put this config file? The link is dead

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use [BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/).
It is pretty straightforward to use, and you can set it up to trigger any action from a keyboard shortcut:
[image: BetterTouchTool screenshot]

However, by doing this, CTRL+C or CTRL+X no longer works as expected inside the terminal. But you can disable BTT for Terminal completely to handle this case.